# jquery tree view checkbox passing values

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jeasyui plugin to achieve tree view functionality. This is the example im using http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree4.php
Here I want to pass json values in a variable instead of json file. Because Im getting json values dynamically and having in my variable. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Lookig at the code If url is not set it returns false, so i think you need to use an url.

But as an alternative you can point the url option to the file wich generates the data.

Something like this.

```
<tag url="http://yourdomain/yourpath/tree_data.php">
```

and in the php file

```
<?php

echo json_encode($my_generated_data);

?>
```